# Origin of the word/root 'del'

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, russian, roots, norwegian

As I was contemplating the Norwegian word "del," which means "part" or "portion," it occurred to me that there is the same root in Russian, and that it means the same thing. I looked up "del" and "делить" (the verb formed from the root "дел"), and here's what I got:

1. [del - Norwegian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/del#Etymology_1_4):

> From Middle Low German dēl, deil, from Old Saxon dēl, from
>   Proto-Germanic *dailą, *dailiz (“part, portion, deal”).

2. [делить - Russian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C#Russian)

> From Proto-Slavic *děliti (“to divide”), from Proto-Balto-Slavic
>   *doyl-, from Proto-Indo-European *dʰayl-, *dʰoyl-. Cognates include Old English dǣlan (English deal) and Lithuanian dailyti.

How do these chains get constructed, and why don't these two lead to the same common ancestor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These words are related, but they do not have any known cognates outside of Germanic and Balto-Slavic. “Proto-Indo-European *dʰayl-, *dʰoyl-“ (as posited on Wikipedia) is highly uncertain. It has been suggested that it is a substrate word.

See the etymology section here: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Teil

Answer (score 4):

They definitely **do** go to the same common ancestor, just the first etymology you found does not go deep enough.

Norwegian *del* is reconstructed to proto-germanic *dailiz*, but that originates from PIE **dhail-*, the etymon for the Slavic *děliti*.

[DEL in Norwegian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/del#Etymology_1_4)

[DAILIZ in Proto-Germanic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/dailiz)

[DĚLIŤ in Russian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C#Russian)

Comment: Some prooflinks would clearly improve this answer.

Comment: The links were already mentioned by the OP so I did no care to elaborate since it was completely sufficient just to investigate them with a little bit more attentiveness.

Comment: If it is on wikipedia it must be true. Why bother with genuine etymological dictionaries?